# Assigning nil to an element on NSMutableDictionary in Objective-C removes that element, is that a sanctioned feature or bug?

Tags: ios, iphone, nsmutabledictionary

I have a `NSMutableDictionary`.

```
NSMutableDictionary * dict = @{
                                @"0" : @"car",
                                @"1" : @"ball",
                                @"2" : @"plane",
}
```

At one point, by error, I was assigning a nil to to an element on a dictionary. For example:

```
  dict[@"1"] = nil;
```

for my surprise, instead of crash, the element "1" is being deleted.

Is this something recent? a sanctioned feature or a bug? I wonder if this is a feature, because I always used something like

```
[dict removeObjectForKey:@"1"];
```

To remove objects from dictionaries.

I never knew it was possible. Perhaps Apple is making Objective-C similar to Swift.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just verified the behavior in Swift 2.0.

```
var dict: NSMutableDictionary = [ "0" : "car", "1" : "ball", "2" : "plane" ];
dict["1"] = nil
print("\(dict)")
```

It must to be a bug because it contradicts the documentation.

From [NSMutableDictionary Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableDictionary/setObject:forKeyedSubscript:):

> - setObject:forKeyedSubscript:
>   Adds a given key-value pair to the dictionary.
>
> ### Declaration
>
> #### OBJECTIVE-C
>
> - (void)setObject:(ObjectType)object
>   forKeyedSubscript:(id)aKey
>
> #### Parameters
>
> object
>
> The value for aKey. A strong reference to the object is maintained by the dictionary.
>
> IMPORTANT
>
> ***Raises an NSInvalidArgumentException if anObject is nil***. If you need to represent a nil value in the dictionary, use NSNull.
>
> aKey
>
> The key for value. The key is copied (using copyWithZone:; keys must conform to the NSCopying protocol). If aKey already exists in the dictionary, anObject takes its place.
>
> IMPORTANT
>
> Raises an NSInvalidArgumentException if aKey is nil.

---

**UPDATE: 2016-04-21**

Apple has updated it's documentation! passing a `nil` value can be used to delete a key.

> object
>
> The value for aKey. A strong reference to the object is maintained by the dictionary.
>
> Passing nil will cause any object corresponding to aKey to be removed from the dictionary.

Comment: @SpaceDog `NSMutableDictionary` is Swift should be the same class as `NSMutableDictionary` in Objective C.

Comment: The value to assign to the specified key. The object must be one of the types listed in Table 1. It is a programmer error to specify an object of any other type. **Specify nil for this parameter to remove the value for the field**. Perhaps Apple updated `NSMutableDictionary to match `CKRecord`. Also as  @Jeffery mentions it may have been necessary to support Swift. My guess is that the documentation is just a little behind.

Comment: Yes, this is what I said. I think Apple is trying to make it like swift. It makes sense and makes the language simple and the documentation, as always, is to forget.

Answer (score 1):

There are different APIs to add an object to a mutable dictionary and they behave differently when you pass `nil`:

- `setObject:forKeyedSubscript:` (a.k.a `dict[key] = nil`) and `setValue:forKey:` accept `nil` and in that case they will remove the object associated corresponding to that key.
- `setObject:forKey:` will raise an exception if `nil` is passed

All this is documented in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutabledictionary